# Eclipse 3.4 - external JARs with environment variables

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, classpath, equinox

I am developing a Plug-in for Lotus Notes (which is Eclipse 3.4) and need to rely on an external SDK/Connector for some Java dependencies and also Configuration files.

It seems that in order to function properly, a file from the Connector installation folder has to be in the classpath. Since I don't know where it's installed, I have to rely on an environment variable that is set during installation ("IBMCMROOT"), which contains the folder.

Is there any way to use Windows environment variables for the classpath definition of eclipse plug-ins? I've tried using variables in the manifest:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: external:$IBMCMROOT$/lib/cmb81.jar,
 $IBMCMROOT$/lib/cmbsdk81.jar,
 $IBMCMROOT$/lib/db2jcc.jar,
 .,
 $IBMCMROOT$/lib/guava-15.0.jar,
 $IBMCMROOT$/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

This results in ClassNotFoundExceptions...

Answer (score 0):

No, Bundle-ClassPath is not used this way. It can only refer to paths within the bundle itself.

In order to load classes from an arbitrary external JAR file at an unknown location, you will need to use a `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: I can't. The classes are not the problem, the configuration files are. The third party libraries try to load configuration files from the classpath. There's no way to overwrite the system classloader to help them find those...

Comment: Then you need to configure Lotus Notes to add these directories to the system classloader. OSGi bundles cannot do anything to alter the global system classpath.

Answer (score 0):

`external:` is an Eclipse containerism. But I think you need to prefix each external jar with `external:`. Also, `IBMCMROOT` must be a system property (not an environment variable). For example, start java with `-DIBMCMROOT=...`

However, I would not do this. Instead, put these necessary jars on the classpath and configure the system bundle to export those package which you can then import from your bundles.

Comment: Which is not possible because - as I described in the question - there's a local installation of a connector which I must reference. I can't ship the libraries in my bundle and I won't hard code the path to configuration files created during installation of this connector.

Comment: I did not say to put the connector in a bundle. I said to put the connector jars on the classpath of the framework and configure to framework to export that connectors packages from the system bundle. Then your bundles which need to use the connector package would import those packages.