# Accessing POI.jar externally through classpath in an eclipse product

Tags: excel, eclipse-plugin, apache-poi, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have developed an eclipse plugin product for which I am using POI.jar to create an excel sheet. I have placed the poi.jar in a folder 'lib' and added the jar into classpath of plugin. When I export the plugin product, it works fine. e.g.: `lib/poi-3.14-20160307.jar`

But when I place the poi.jar in an external folder and access it through an environment path, after exporting the product it is not working. Please see the attached image. e.g.: `external:$PRODUCT_PATH$/poi-3.14-20160307.jar` where PRODUCT_PATH is an environment variable which points to a specific location.

This is the error I am getting:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;      
The import org.apache.poi cannot be resolved.

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
The import org.apache.poi cannot be resolved.
```

[image: accessing externally throws error]

Comment: @ck1 In eclipse plugin development, we do not use ${PRODUCT_PATH}

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562370/eclipse-plugin-with-external-third-party-jar

Comment: @KondalKolipaka : I am able to access ojdbc4.jar using the environment variable technique. In case of poi jar, even the solution suggested in the above link doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

The below link helped me to solve my problem. 
 stackoverflow.com/questions/27562370/

I have added two entries for the same jar in runtime-classpath. One pointing to the 'lib' folder kept in the project and other one pointing to the external path. while exporting it will use the jar kept in 'lib' folder for compilation. after exporting the product remove the jar from the 'lib' folder.

It will use the external path to access the jar while running the exported product.